# How to access the capture group in a regex subroutine?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a pattern that I want to use in a couple of places, but I want access to an inner part of the pattern.  Is there a way to do this?

In this *simplified* example:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<_isa_> \s+ (?<isa> is \s+ a) \s+ )
)
this (?&_isa_) (?<test>test)
```

I'd like to have access to the matched captured string in the named group `isa` when the regex succeeds, without having to pull out the surrounding `\s+` like so:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<_isa_> is \s+ a )
)
this \s+ (?<isa>(?&_isa_)) \s+ (?<test>test)
```

Because, this would basically mean that I have to specify a pre-submatch, submatch and post-submatch every time I want to do this in my actual regex, which is not what I want.

Comment: It is not possible, the capture groups inside a DEFINE block are only "visible" inside that block and cannot be accessed from the pattern.

Comment: You *could* perhaps hack something with the callout mechanism if your tool/language exposes that, but you'd also get results from failed branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, as the capture groups inside a `DEFINE` block are only "visible" inside that block and cannot be accessed from the pattern.

See this [`perlre` reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> This allows one to define subpatterns which will be executed only by the recursion mechanism... **Note that capture groups matched inside of recursion are not accessible after the recursion returns, so the *extra layer of capturing groups is necessary*.**
>   ...
>   Finally, keep in mind that subpatterns created inside a `DEFINE` block count towards the absolute and relative number of captures.

So, even though you have 3 named capture groups, you can only access `test` group that was defined in the main pattern.